# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'after'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to loop the function repeatedly with this code which gives me the error as the question.

```
async def looptrack(ctx, *times):
    global timess
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        if voice and voice.is_playing():
            if os.path.exists(audio):
                if times:
                    times = int(''.join(map(str, times)))
                    timess = str(times)
                    if (timess == "0"):
                        global looptrack_infinite
                        looptrack_infinite = await ctx.send("Will loop "+vTT+" infinite times")                                
                        await tracklooper(0)    
                    else:
                        global looptrack_set_times
                        looptrack_set_times = await ctx.send("Will loop "+vTT+" for "+timess+" times")
                        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio, after=lambda e: looptrack(ctx)))
                else:
                    global looptrack_fail
                    looptrack_fail = await ctx.send("Please enter the number of times to repeat, 0 for infinite times") 
                    await looptrack_fail.delete(delay=10)
            else:
                global looptrack_no_audio
                looptrack_no_audio = await ctx.send("Audio file not found")
                await looptrack_no_audio.delete(delay=10)
        else:
            global looptrack_notin_channel
            looptrack_notin_channel = await ctx.send("No song loaded")
            await looptrack_notin_channel.delete(delay=10)
    else:
        looptrack_client_notcn = await ctx.send("You are not connected to any voice channel")
        await looptrack_client_notcn.delete(delay=10)
```

This is a part of the code in my discord bot where i am trying to play a music in the voice channel repeatedly if the command `looptrack` is called

Edit: as suggested, I replaced the line

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio, after=lambda e: looptrack(ctx)))
```

with

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio), after=lambda e: looptrack(ctx))
```

which now throws a new error

```
Warning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  self.after(error)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing an `await` statement.  I tend to sprinkle `print()` statements and `try..except` blocks to help show where I am in the code and the vicinity of the error.

Comment: I am new to python programming, so I am unable to check where I am missing `await`. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: I am unable to help with await, as I have not done any async programming yet with python.  I was just reading the error message you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line that gives an error with:

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio), after=lambda e: looptrack(ctx))
```

You put one closing parenthesis in the wrong place. `after` should be an argument to `play`, not `FFmpegPCMAudio`.

Comment: adding the line you sent did fix the problem, however I now get a new error

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: await voice.play(...)